# Why is flask_wtf.FlaskForm to upload a file is giving an error saying the file isn't uploaded?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

**Edit**

If I call `request.files['file']` I get the file object, but `form.validate_on_submit()` still fails. Why is it failing if the file object is there in the request?

---

I have three files:

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired

class ExcelForm(FlaskForm):
    excel_file = FileField(validators=[
        FileRequired()
    ])
```

**webapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from forms import ExcelForm
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '314159265358'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = ExcelForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        df = pd.read_csv(form.excel_file.data)
        print(df.head())

        return redirect(url_for('hello', name=form.excel_file.data))
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)

@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name):
    return 'hello' + name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**templates\upload.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
 <input type = "file" name = "file" />
 <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I can access `localhost:5000/upload` with no issues. I click the Browse button, select my file, then click the Submit button.

In the `webapp.py` `upload` function, the `form.validate_on_submit()` fails and gives me an error saying `{'excel_file': ['This field is required.']}`. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I don't want to save the file locally either to read it in later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render your form fields how [flask-wtforms](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/) specifies.

Practically copied from their docs...

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
{% block content %}
<form method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field(form.file) }}
    {{ render_field(form.submit) }} <!-- add a submit button to your form -->
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Then create the macro

**_formhelpers.html**

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, with adding a submit button to the Excel form. I still get the same `form.error` saying there's no file.